# Is there a way to form network connections using shell script?

Tags: 13.04, scripts

I want to form a network connection to a website and read the data line by line and store it in a text file in my system using shell scripting. I have done it using java where I can read using a URLConnection object to that particular resource. 
In shell scripting is WGET Spider the only way to do it? If not what other ways are there to read text file from a website, parse it and store it in my local directory?

**EDIT**
I tried using WGET using `wget -o /home/user/Desktop/training.txt https://www.someurl.com`. But the output is something like this

```
--2014-04-15 00:39:15--  https://s3.amazonaws.com/hr-testcases/368/assets/trainingdata.txt
Resolving s3.amazonaws.com (s3.amazonaws.com)... 176.32.99.154
Connecting to s3.amazonaws.com (s3.amazonaws.com)|176.32.99.154|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1554016 (1.5M) [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘trainingdata.txt.1’

     0K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  3% 47.5K 31s
    50K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  6%  129K 20s
   100K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  9%  136K 16s
   150K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 13%  149K 14s
   200K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 16% 1.57M 11s
   250K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 19%  162K 10s
   300K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 23%  678K 9s
   350K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 26%  612K 7s
   400K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 29%  307K 7s
   450K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 32%  630K 6s
   500K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 36%  699K 5s
   550K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 39%  520K 5s
   600K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 42%  580K 4s
   650K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 46%  516K 4s
   700K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 49%  551K 3s
   750K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 52%  713K 3s
   800K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 56%  720K 3s
   850K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 59%  701K 2s
   900K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 62%  603K 2s
   950K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 65%  670K 2s
  1000K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 69%  715K 2s
  1050K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 72%  671K 1s
  1100K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 75%  752K 1s
  1150K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 79%  535K 1s
  1200K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 82%  607K 1s
  1250K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 85%  675K 1s
  1300K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 88%  727K 1s
  1350K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 92%  707K 0s
  1400K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 95%  632K 0s
  1450K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 98%  785K 0s
  1500K .......... .......                                    100%  931K=4.5s

2014-04-15 00:39:23 (341 KB/s) - ‘trainingdata.txt.1’ saved [1554016/1554016]
```

It only seems to give the statistics like the time taken to download and all. It does not give save the actual data from the url.

Comment: @terdon Oh ok. Can't I control the location of the downloaded file?

Comment: No, hang on, my bad. Writing an answer now. What you're saving is the standard error.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want [netcat](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/),

> Netcat is a featured networking utility which reads and writes data across network connections, using the TCP/IP protocol.
>   It is designed to be a reliable "back-end" tool that can be used directly or easily driven by other programs and scripts. At the same time, it is a feature-rich network debugging and exploration tool, since it can create almost any kind of connection you would need and has several interesting built-in capabilities.

for more, you can always `man nc`

Comment: how is netcat different form wget?

Comment: @Ashwin From `man wget` -  GNU Wget is a free utility for non-interactive download of files from the Web. In contrast, netcat is for scripting network connections.

Answer (score 1):

The command you are running is using the `-o` flag which does (from `man wget`):

```
   -o logfile
   --output-file=logfile
       Log all messages to logfile.  The messages are normally reported to
       standard error.
```

It does not actually save the target of the URL to that file, only the standard error of `wget`. By default, `wget` saves the target with the same name as the remote file. Do, for example this

```
wget http://www.foo.com/index.html
```

will save the file as `index.html` in your current directory. To specify a different name for the file, use `-O` (CAPITAL `o`, as in Oliver) instead:

```
   -O file
   --output-document=file
       The documents will not be written to the appropriate files, but all
       will be concatenated together and written to file.  If - is used as
       file, documents will be printed to standard output, disabling link
       conversion.  (Use ./- to print to a file literally named -.)

       Use of -O is not intended to mean simply "use the name file instead
       of the one in the URL;" rather, it is analogous to shell
       redirection: wget -O file http://foo is intended to work like wget
       -O - http://foo > file; file will be truncated immediately, and all
       downloaded content will be written there.
```